# Dual boot laptop boots directly into windows 11 even with Windows Boot manager completely disabled

Tags: windows, dual-boot, pop-os

I have a laptop with two OSs on it, Windows and Pop OS. I used rEFIned to choose between the two however that stopped working a while ago (which I intend to fix), and just booted straight to Linux. Yesterday after changing the boot order to go back to Windows, I let Windows update, and now, no matter how I change the boot order, Windows always boots first. I even completely disabled the Windows Boot Manager and had Pop OS first in the boot order and Windows still boots. I'm unsure of what to do.

Comment: When you say first in boot order are you seeing UEFI boot order or Boot Manager's boot order, either rEFInd or POP? Window or LInux systems with major updates to boot loaders/managers typically change boot order so they are first. Windows also may update UEFI which reverts UEFI settings to defaults. So check UEFI settings. Windows may also turn on fast start up or other settings, preventing Linux from seeing the Windows install.

Comment: specifically in the UEFI, i set to boot order to pop os first and disabled windows boot manager. even after rebooting and everything it still always shows windows boot manager disabled and Pop OS first

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Do not run any fixes from Boot-Repair as it normally just installs grub2, it does not repair SystemD boot. But report can tell us about your configuration.

Comment: ah unfortunately i just gave up and completely reinstalled the popOS boot loader, so i cant really say what happened now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be not actually shutting down. See:
https://www.howtogeek.com/349114/shutting-down-doesnt-fully-shut-down-windows-10-but-restarting-it-does/

As far as I know this applies to later versions too.
In short: Try holding shift when clicking on the shutdown option in Windows.